# Ethernet connection drops frequently and randomly

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu, ethernet

I've been experiencing problems with my ethernet connection. The connection drops and comes unexpectedly and randomly, I've been monitoring that by pinging to google. When it drops I can make it return by unplugging and plugging the wire. It also returns when I execute the next command: `sudo arp-scan -I eno2 -l`. I've got a DELL precision laptop, Kubuntu 18.04 and this is the info of my Ethernet driver, e1000e for an intel I219-LM:

```
[    1.869486] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    1.869487] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    1.869811] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    2.299008] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    2.373257] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) c8:f7:50:3c:cf:e4
[    2.373258] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    2.373391] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 13, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    2.374175] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno2: renamed from eth0
[    4.157737] Modules linked in: hid_generic usbhid nouveau(+) i915 rtsx_pci_sdmmc mxm_wmi ttm i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt e1000e fb_sys_fops ahci rtsx_pci drm libahci i2c_hid hid pinctrl_cannonlake wmi video pinctrl_intel
[    4.157948] Modules linked in: hid_generic usbhid nouveau(+) i915 rtsx_pci_sdmmc mxm_wmi ttm i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt e1000e fb_sys_fops ahci rtsx_pci drm libahci i2c_hid hid pinctrl_cannonlake wmi video pinctrl_intel
[   35.234229] e1000e: eno2 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   35.234236] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno2: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[  481.481488] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno2: removed PHC
[  481.566108] e1000e: eno2 NIC Link is Down
[  484.350727] e1000e: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  484.351713] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.6.0-NAPI
[  484.351713] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2019 Intel Corporation.
[  484.351966] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[  484.591624] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[  484.678922] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) c8:f7:50:3c:cf:e4
[  484.678926] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[  484.679054] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 13, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[  484.684847] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno2: renamed from eth0
[  488.421904] e1000e: eno2 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[  488.421910] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno2: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
```

Hope you can Help me.

Comment: Look at the logs with `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`

Comment: Also, replace the Ethernet cables. They do fail, and it's quick to check for.

Comment: @K7AAY, there is no problem with Ethernet cables, I have already replaced the cable and the problem persists. I have checked if the cable works with another laptop, and it works, it just doesn't work with my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it by changing IP. I just set up a dynamic IP and that fixed the problem, don't know why, but that fixed the problem.